# How to paste a vector of strings on a column based on the levels of another?

Tags: r, dataframe, split, lapply

I'm trying to apply a unique identity to a series of respondent names based on levels of a factor. I'm using lapply(paste0) but not making any headway.

```
library(dplyr)
q46 <- data_frame(
  coop=sample(c('fish','dairy','legumes'),20,replace=T),
  name=sample(c('Leader','President','Agronomist'),20,replace = T)
)
y <- c('.f','.d','.l')
coop_split <- split(q46, q46$coop)

lapply(split(q46,q46$coop), function(x) {
  paste0(q46$name,y[i])})
```

The desired output is like this:

```
 name

 Leader.f

 President.f

 Leader.d
```

I'm not stuck on this approach; is there a function that does this automatically?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use case_when or ifelse?

```
library(tidyverse)
q46 %>% 
    mutate(name2 = case_when(coop=='legumes' ~paste0(name, ".l"),
                             coop=='fish' ~paste0(name,".f"),
                             coop=='dairy' ~paste0(name, ".d")))

# A tibble: 20 x 3
  coop       name        name2
 <chr>      <chr>        <chr>
 1 legumes     Leader     Leader.l
 2    fish     Leader     Leader.f
 3 legumes  President  President.l
 4 legumes  President  President.l
 5   dairy     Leader     Leader.d
 6 legumes Agronomist Agronomist.l
 7 legumes  President  President.l
 8    fish Agronomist Agronomist.f
 9    fish     Leader     Leader.f
10 legumes     Leader     Leader.l
11 legumes Agronomist Agronomist.l
12 legumes Agronomist Agronomist.l
13 legumes  President  President.l
14    fish Agronomist Agronomist.f
15   dairy     Leader     Leader.d
16   dairy  President  President.d
17 legumes Agronomist Agronomist.l
18 legumes  President  President.l
19 legumes     Leader     Leader.l
20 legumes Agronomist Agronomist.l
```

Comment: This works well and I like the dplyr approach, but I've got many, many coops.  I'm looking for a way to loop or lapply using the unique values in a column.

Comment: If all the coops have different names (first letters) then use `q46 %>% 
 mutate(name2 = paste0(name, ".",substr(coop, 1, 1)))`